# What am I doing wrong when invoking AWS API ListSuppressedDestinations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to retrieve a list of emails (that are on the suppressed list) from the AWS SES service.
For this I am making a request to the Amazon WS API using the **ListSuppressedDestinations** "Action". And I'm signing the requests with "Signature Version 4".
I don't use the AWS SDK due to incompatibility with the production environment.

The problem is that I do not receive data, but a response that I do not understand. Here is the answer:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
        <Message>Could not find operation ListSuppressedDestinations for version 2019-09-27</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>6aac7741-7ef3-4be8-b34f-324355346d79</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

The expected response: (obtained with the AWS SDK for php)

```php
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'EmailAddress' => string 'email1@domain.com' (length=25)
      'Reason' => string 'BOUNCE' (length=6)
      'LastUpdateTime' => 
        object(Aws\Api\DateTimeResult)[114]
          public 'date' => string '2022-05-30 17:49:23.401000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'EmailAddress' => string 'email2@domain.com' (length=24)
      'Reason' => string 'BOUNCE' (length=6)
      'LastUpdateTime' => 
        object(Aws\Api\DateTimeResult)[127]
          public 'date' => string '2022-05-30 17:19:02.851000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

Minimum, reproducible example

```php
<?php
$accessKey = "ACCESSKEY";
$secretKey = "SECRETKEY";

$hostApi = "email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
$verbo = "GET";
$path = "";

$parameters = Array();
setParameter('Action', 'ListSuppressedDestinations');
setParameter('Version', '2019-09-27');

ksort($parameters);
$query = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC1738);
$resulset = requestCurl($hostApi, $parameters, 'GET');
var_dump($resulset);


function requestCurl($hostApi, $parameters = array(), $method = 'GET') {

        global $hostApi;
        global $path;
        
      $url = 'https://'.$hostApi.'/'.$path;
        ksort($parameters);
        $query = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC1738);
        $headers = getHeaders($query);

        /*
         * Opciones de CURL
         */
        $curlOption = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?' . $query,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
        );


        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlOption);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
                return $err;
        }

        return $response;
}


function setParameter($key, $value, $replace = true) {
    
    global $parameters;
    
    if(!$replace && isset($this->parameters[$key])) {
        $temp = (array)($this->parameters[$key]);
        $temp[] = $value;
        $parameters[$key] = $temp;
    } else {
        $parameters[$key] = $value;
    }

}

function getHeaders($query) {
    
        global $hostApi;

        $headers = array();

        $date = (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
        $headers[] = 'X-Amz-Date: ' . $date;
        $headers[] = 'Host: ' . $hostApi;
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: ' . getAuthHeaderV4($date, $query);

        return $headers;
}


function getAuthHeaderV4($amz_datetime, $query) {
                
        global $hostApi;
        global $verbo;
        global $secretKey;
        global $accessKey;
        global $hostApi;
        global $path;
        
        $amz_date = substr($amz_datetime, 0, 8);
        $algo = 'sha256';
        $aws_algo = 'AWS4-HMAC-' . strtoupper($algo);

        $host_parts = explode('.', $hostApi );
        $service = $host_parts[0];
//      $service = "sesv2";
        $region = 'us-east-1';

        $canonical_uri = 'https://'.$hostApi.'/'.$path.'/';
        if($verbo === 'POST') {
                $canonical_querystring = '';
                $payload_data = $query;
        } else {
                $canonical_querystring = $query;
                $payload_data = '';
        }
        
        // ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
        $canonical_headers_list = [
                'host:' . $hostApi,
                'x-amz-date:' . $amz_datetime
        ];

        $canonical_headers = implode("\n", $canonical_headers_list) . "\n";
        
        $signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date';
        $payload_hash = hash($algo, $payload_data, false);

        $canonical_request = implode("\n", array(
                $verbo,
                $canonical_uri,
                $canonical_querystring,
                $canonical_headers,
                $signed_headers,
                $payload_hash
        ));


        // ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
        $credential_scope = $amz_date. '/' . $region . '/' . $service . '/' . 'aws4_request';

        $string_to_sign = implode("\n", array(
                $aws_algo,
                $amz_datetime,
                $credential_scope,
                hash($algo, $canonical_request, false)
        ));

        // ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
        // Create the signing key using the function defined above.
        $signing_key = getSigningKey($secretKey, $amz_date, $region, $service, $algo);

        // Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
        $signature = hash_hmac($algo, $string_to_sign, $signing_key, false);

        // ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************

        
        return $aws_algo . ' ' . implode(', ', array(
                        'Credential=' . $accessKey . '/' . $credential_scope,
                        'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers ,
                        'Signature=' . $signature
                ));
}

function getSigningKey($key, $dateStamp, $regionName, $serviceName, $algo) {
        $kDate = hash_hmac($algo, $dateStamp, 'AWS4' . $key, true);
        $kRegion = hash_hmac($algo, $regionName, $kDate, true);
        $kService = hash_hmac($algo, $serviceName, $kRegion, true);

        return hash_hmac($algo,'aws4_request', $kService, true);
}
```

Comment: Try `email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2`

Comment: hello!, I did the test that you indicated, but it did not work. He answered this:
`<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Three issues:  1: The `$path` needs to be `"/v2/email/suppression/addresses"` 2: The `$service` needs to be `"ses"` 3: The second part of `$canonical_request`, what is now `$canonical_uri`, should be `$path`

Comment: It worked.
Thanks to all for the help!